# How to make a table with two fixed columns responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have a table with two fixed columns, one on the left and one on the right.

At the moment it only works in one resolution. But when the resolution is changed, the column on the right gets very messed up.

This is the main class that controls the margins (to allow room for the fixed columns) along with the width:

```
#myTable > .wrapper {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: visible;
    width: 83%;
    margin-left: 126px;
    margin-right: 45px;
}
```

I have tried going into the developer tools and changing the width value down as I resize the browser. So far, this is the only solution I have found. Although, this would requre tons of media queries which is not a preferable solution.

How could I possibly edit my `css` classes to make this responsive?

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QB2aa/)

Comment: you want the table to scale down/up in size and reposition itself on windows resizing or just one or the other?

Comment: change that css class from `position:absolute;` to `position:fixed` ?

Comment: Within the example, resize the window the result is in. You will notice that the far right column (that has an absolute position) will eventually get merged within the rest of the table and will look very out of place. Changing it to position `fixed` will not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try limiting the width of the wrapper by using `min-width` and `max-width`:

```
#myTable > .wrapper {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: visible;
    max-width: 83%;
    min-width: 40%;
    margin-left: 126px;
    margin-right: 45px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QB2aa/1/)**

Comment: Great, works quite well. Will just need to play around with it a bit more to get it spot on, but thanks for the solution :)